# Find shortcut for multiple windows

Tags: ios, xcode, editor, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to toggle find option in assistant editor? I was able to do it in two steps

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> (to navigate to another tab)
2. <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>f</kbd>  (to open finder)

Can we make it done in one step? like we use <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>f</kbd> to open find for whole project.

[image]